# How to select text between strings held in ArrayList

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-tika

Can't figure this out. I am using apache POI to select out text that is bold from a .doc. I've added this to an array list. I would like to select text from the .doc that lies between consecutive strings in the arrayList and then store each selected section seperately.

In other words I have this:

```
MyBold title
Bla
bla
fsfs
bn
whtrh

More bold title

gfgdgdfs
dsgfd
gfdg

Another title of some kind
```

The resulting arrayList gives me this:

```
MyBold title
More bold title
Another title of some kind
```

And I want to get this as separate string objects 
First object:

```
MyBold title
    Bla
    bla
    fsfs
    bn
    whtrh
```

Second object:

```
More bold title

    gfgdgdfs
    dsgfd
    gfdg
```

Third object:

```
Another title of some kind
```

My code so far:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.CharacterRun;

public class Impedance {
    String REGEX = "[A-Z]+";
    public Impedance()  {
    }

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         public static void Update() throws IOException {
    try{
    String fileName = "/Users/IMPEDANCE.doc";
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);  
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);  
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  

    Range range = doc.getRange();
    WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
    Paragraph r =range.getParagraph(0);
    ArrayList<String> bold1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<range.numCharacterRuns(); i++)
    {


            CharacterRun cr = range.getCharacterRun(i);
            if(cr.isBold())
            {
            System.out.println(cr.text());
            bold1.add(cr.text());
            }

    }



    for (String bold : bold1) {
    //How to iterate through array list and return the string section between consecutive parts of the arraylist
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map where the key are the titles, and value is a List of Strings.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map  = new Hashmap<>();
String currentTitle = null;

for(int i = 0; i<range.numCharacterRuns(); i++){

    CharacterRun cr = range.getCharacterRun(i);

    //if the cr is bold, add it as a title
    if(cr.isBold()){

        currentTitle = cr.text();
        map.put(currentTitle, new ArrayList<String>());

        }else{

            //if the cr is not bold, get the last inserted title and
            //add the cr to its String list

            List<String> list = map.get(currentTitle);

            if(list != null){

                list.add(cr.text());
                map.put(currentTitle, list);
           }

        }
}
```

Comment: Thats OK for storing, but how to select in the first place

Comment: I edit the answer, please let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: I had to change the List arguments as I think List is generic (so I removed <String>. However I now get the error java.lang.NullPointerException at the line list.add(currentTitle)

Comment: @SebastianZeki, you're right, List is generic, but you still need to inform the type, removing the <String> will give you a raw type. Read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.htm).

Comment: Using the code above I still get a NullPointerException and I'm not sure why

Comment: In what line do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: This was happening because you could run into a non bold string, before hitting a title, and hence there wasn't any list to add it. I fixed the answer.